# Powershell V2 + PSRemoteRegistry Getting information from (Default) vaules

Tags: powershell, registry, powershell-2.0

I'm currently writing a script that will scan a list of servers and check a certain REG_SZ registry value. My code works perfectly until I need to read from a (Default) value.

Examples

```
$regValue = (Get-RegString -Hive LocalMachine -Key "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InifileMapping\control.ini" -Value Current).data
```

This returns good data.

```
$regValue = (Get-RegString -Hive LocalMachine -Key "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InifileMapping\RegEdt32.ini" -Value Default).data
```

This returns "Cannot find value [Default] because it does not exist.

```
$regValue = (Get-RegString -Hive LocalMachine -Key "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InifileMapping\RegEdt32.ini" -Value "(Default)").data
```

This returns "Cannot find value [(Default)] because it does not exist.

I'm open to using other methods to get the values.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Get-RegString is part of the very common PSRemoteRegistry module which is listed in the title. I made a mistake with my copy and pasted code, it should be regedt32.ini (Default) value. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## One Method

The [PSRemoteRegistry](https://psremoteregistry.codeplex.com/) module actually includes a command specifically for retrieving registry key default values: `Get-RegDefault`

Using your example, the command and resulting output:

> ```
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (Get-RegDefault -Hive LocalMachine -Key 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InifileMapping\RegEdt32.ini').Data
> ```
>
> USR:Software\Microsoft\RegEdt32

There is a potential problem with using `Get-RegDefault`, which is the error it throws when there is no data set at all for the "(Default)" key value:

> ```
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (Get-RegDefault -Hive LocalMachine -Key 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InifileMapping').Data
> ```
>
> Get-RegDefault : Exception calling "GetValueKind" with "1" argument(s): "The specified registry key does not exist."
>   At line:1 char:2
>   + (Get-RegDefault -Hive LocalMachine -Key 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows N ...
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>        + CategoryInfo             : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Get-RegDefault

A fairly straightforward workaround would be to simply use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to suppress the error, as it is non-terminating, however, that is not recommended practice.

---

## Better Method

The *name* of the "(Default)" registry key value is actually empty. The reason your original commands returned an error about the value not existing, is because there truly is no key value with the name of "(Default)" unless you maybe created one.

So the most simple and clean way to check for a key's default value is to use the `Get-RegValue` command and pass an empty string as the value name.

This example shows the result when a legitimate  "(Default)" value with data has been found:

> ```
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (Get-RegValue -Hive LocalMachine -Key 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InifileMapping\RegEdt32.ini' -Value '').Data
> ```
>
> USR:Software\Microsoft\RegEdt32

Here is an example using the key that produced an error previously:

> ```
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (Get-RegValue -Hive LocalMachine -Key "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InifileMapping" -Value '').Data
> ```

As you can see nothing is returned at all because the "Default" value of that key has no data. As a bonus, if the key itself truly did not exist, then you would still be able to detect that by not suppressing errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not specifically tied to Get-RegString, you can use Get-RegValue from the same PSRemoteRegistry module.  You can tack on the '-type String' parameter to restrict this to a string if necessary.

You just point it at the key where the default value exists.  Example workflow to test:

```
#Stage a key to test:
    #Create a 'blah' key under HKLM\Software.
    #Change the default value to some desired value.

#Get the default value (assumes no other values exist under this key)
    (Get-RegValue -Hive LocalMachine -Key SOFTWARE\blah).data

#Get the default value, accounting for other potential values
    Get-Regvalue -Hive LocalMachine -Key SOFTWARE\Blah | Where-Object {$_.value -like "(Default)"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty data

#Get the default value, limited to string type:
    (get-RegValue -Hive LocalMachine -Key SOFTWARE\blah -Type String).data
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! While this gets all the values, my script knows what it is looking for so I can just compare against the returned strings.

I appreciate your assistance.